# Code Reveiw Help (IF-statement)

Tags: apex, community

I have a lead that was created yesterday.  My second IF statement is checking to see if the createddate is equal to today date, and it clearly doesn't.  Then how come it executes the next if statement?  I'm expecting it to exist my nested IF statements.

Please help. Thanks

```
if(leadIdMap.get(lead.Id).Status == 'Not Ready For Sales'){
    if(leadIdMap.get(lead.Id).Createddate.date() ==  system.Today()){
      if(queueIdMap.keyset().contains(lead.OwnerId)) {
         lead.OwnerId = queueId; //"Not Ready For Sales"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what makes you say that the trigger approves the 2nd loop and proceeds further into the 3rd if loop?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have your timezone configured in such a way that the record is considered to be created today?

Answer (score 2):

Thankyou everyone.  I found the problem.  This trigger was a campaign member trigger.  It was supposed to compare the LEAD creation date to today date.  Instead, I mistakenly compare the campaign member creation date to today date.  That is why it always true.

Comment: This was someone else code I'm taken over.  Thank you all for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, in your code it is getting the creation date of the Map, not the record itself (based on your description, I assume this is the issue).

If this is a trigger, I suppose you could query for the `CreatedDate` attribute, and compare it to `System.Today()`.

Comment: Do Maps have a CreatedDate?

Comment: I don't know. But that seemed logical looking at your code. :P

Comment: This is a good example of why maps should be named like `leadIdToLeadMap`. The map doesn't have a createdDate; the get(..) on the map returns a Lead sobject that has fields, one of which is createdDate